# Creating a new column based on lagged/changing variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**UPDATED**

I have a df which looks like the following:

```
print(df)

           id  rank  a  
date                      
2000-01-01  1   1.0  0  
2000-01-01  2   3.0  0  
2000-01-01  3   2.0  0  
2000-01-01  4   0.0  0  
2000-01-02  1   2.0  0
2000-01-02  2   3.0  0  
2000-01-02  3   2.0  0  
2000-01-02  4   1.0  0
2000-01-03  1   3.0  0 
2000-01-03  2   2.0  0 
2000-01-03  3   1.0  0 
2000-01-03  4   1.0  0
```

I am wanting to create a new variable `a` which is equal to 1 if `rank`changes from the previous month. For example, in `2000-01-01` `rank` is 3.0 and in `2000-01-02` it changes to 2.0. I would like this change to correspond with a 1 in `a` and if no change, stay 0. I want to groupby `id` aswell. Also, rank can only increase by 1 over each period.

**Expected Output**

```
           id  rank  a  
date                      
2000-01-01  1   1.0  1 
2000-01-01  2   3.0  1  
2000-01-01  3   2.0  1  
2000-01-01  4   0.0  1  
2000-01-02  1   2.0  1
2000-01-02  2   3.0  0  
2000-01-02  3   2.0  0  
2000-01-02  4   1.0  1
2000-01-03  1   3.0  1 
2000-01-03  2   2.0  1 
2000-01-03  3   1.0  1 
2000-01-03  4   1.0  0
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `a` does not look like a `variable`.

Comment: First value in `a` is missing value? Or empty string?

Comment: You should probably clarify what's the expected output if the rank changes by >1 in a single step.

Comment: Updated as I need to groupby with `id` aswell now!

Comment: @oceanbeach96 - edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and if possible difference more like `1` use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['a'] = df['rank'].diff().abs().clip(upper=1)
```

If difference is always only `1`:

```
df['a'] = df['rank'].diff().abs()
```

And if need first value set to `0`:

```
df['a'] = df['rank'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0).astype(int)
```

EDITED answer:

```
df['a1'] = df.groupby('id')['rank'].diff().ne(0).astype(int)
print (df)
          date  id  rank  a  a1
0   2000-01-01   1   1.0  1   1
1   2000-01-01   2   3.0  1   1
2   2000-01-01   3   2.0  1   1
3   2000-01-01   4   0.0  1   1
4   2000-01-02   1   2.0  1   1
5   2000-01-02   2   3.0  0   0
6   2000-01-02   3   2.0  0   0
7   2000-01-02   4   1.0  1   1
8   2000-01-03   1   3.0  1   1
9   2000-01-03   2   2.0  1   1
10  2000-01-03   3   1.0  1   1
11  2000-01-03   4   1.0  0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"rank": [3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]})

df['a'] = (df['rank'] - df['rank'].shift(1)).abs()
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
   rank    a
0   3.0  NaN
1   2.0  1.0
2   2.0  0.0
3   2.0  0.0
4   1.0  1.0
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to replace the `NaN` with empty string:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna('').astype(str)
```

**EDIT 2**:

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), Since the above snippet would give the actual difference, where using this approach gives you 1 for a difference and 0 otherwise:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"rank": [3.0, 12.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]})

df['a'] = np.where((df['rank'] - df['rank'].shift(1)).abs() > 0, 1, 0)
print(df)
```

Comment: This assumes rank changes by exactly +-1 or not at all

Comment: It runs, but outputs eg. 2 whereas I believe what is being requested is an indicator function for a change having occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `np.select`

```
df0 = df.shift()
cond1 = df0['rank'].isnull()   # to set first row nan
cond2 = df0['rank'] != df['rank']

df['a'] = np.select([cond1,cond2], [0,1], 0)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d['a'] = (d['rank'].shift() == d['rank']).map({True:0, False:1})
```

Notice that the first element of column `a` is `1`. Remove it if you don't need it.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Also this could be done as using [Series.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and converting the series of booleans directly to integers as:

```
df['a']=df['rank'].diff().eq(-1).astype(int)
```